# I need to add a word after the first word in google sheet

Tags: arrays, regex, google-sheets, replace, google-sheets-formula

I have a set of sentences written in thousands of cells and I need to add a single word after the first word.

For example, these sentences start with

```
"Buy [NAME OF THE PRODUCT]+[FEATURE]+[PRICE]".
```

So, I need to add `the` after `Buy`.

Is this possible without getting into too much coding?

Cheers and be well!

Comment: Is this something you want done in place (i.e., do you want the original to be changed)? Or do you want a copy of the original that has the extra "the" after "Buy"? And to help me be most direct, which column (letter) are these sentences in right now?

Comment: Preferably, I want the original sentence to remain untouched beyond adding the word "the" after "Buy" but whatever you feel work best I just need to get this done.

Answer (score 1):

Just Find and replace "Buy" with "Buy the".

If you turn on "Search using regular expressions" you can ensure that you only catch "Buy" at the beginning with the search string "^Buy". (The ^ indicates the start of the cell.)

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your original sentences are in Column A. Do the following:

1.) Click the "A" at the top of the column to select the entire column.

2.) Click Ctrl-H to open the Find/Replace dialog window.

3.) In the `Find` field, type "Buy " (i.e., the word **Buy** with a space after it, no quotation marks).

4.) In the `Replace with` field, type "Buy the " (i.e., the words **Buy the** with a space afterward, no quotation marks).

5.) Make sure the choices after `Search` are "Specific range" and the column you have selected.

6.) Click the "Replace all" button at the bottom.

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(A1:A2, "^([^ ]+)", "$1 The"))
```

[image]

or directly:

select a range & press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> and do:

[image]